# GDAL import fails from IPython only

Tags: python, anaconda, ipython, gdal

I am trying to import `gdal` in IPython.

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

The import works fine from "regular" Python, but fails from IPython (and jupyter), the full traceback is shown at the end.

I am using anaconda version 4.5.11, Python version 3.6.6, IPython version 7.0.1 on MacOS 10.14. 
I also use homebrew.

This is in a clean anaconda environment that only contains the following:
`conda create -n gdal gdal ipython`

What can possibly cause the import to succeed in python, but to fail in IPython?

---

```
In [1]: from osgeo import gdal                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-61e0eefce4de> in <module>
----> 1 from osgeo import gdal

/anaconda3/envs/gdal/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py in <module>
     19                 fp.close()
     20             return _mod
---> 21     _gdal = swig_import_helper()
     22     del swig_import_helper
     23 else:

/anaconda3/envs/gdal/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py in swig_import_helper()
     15         if fp is not None:
     16             try:
---> 17                 _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
     18             finally:
     19                 fp.close()

/anaconda3/envs/gdal/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241                 return load_dynamic(name, filename, opened_file)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:
    245         return load_package(name, filename)

/anaconda3/envs/gdal/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341         spec = importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 
    345 else:

ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/envs/gdal/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _libiconv
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/envs/gdal/lib/libspatialite.7.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
 in /anaconda3/envs/gdal/lib/libspatialite.7.dylib
```

---

**EDIT**:

I have had similar issues arise with the modules `lxml.etree` and `cv2`, all of which I can consistently import from `python` without problems.

I have found that the main issue seems to be that for IPython I need to set the environment variable `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, while Python is happily accepting `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I would be very happy if somebody could explain to me why that is the case.

Furthermore, I can only import `cv2` from IPython if I install it via `pip install opencv-python`, but not if I install it via `conda install opencv`. Regular python is happy to import both.

For both `cv2` and `gdal`, correctly linking the library `libiconv` appears to be the key.

Any clues as to this paradoxical behavior would be much appreciated!